# Does Flip Out affect the player that activated it?

Tags: 100-percent-orange-juice

The description for Flip Out states "Next time you land on a drop panel, the player(s) with the highest number of stars will lose the same number of stars as you."

What happens if a player activates Flip Out, then lands on a drop panel while they have the most stars? Will the player lose twice as many stars? Or will the card have no effect?